# How can I get current used application name on screen?

Tags: android

I want to detect which app is open right now and perform some action according to the Android App. whether my app is running in the background or not. 
if you want to downvote me I appreciate but please mention in the comment why you do this?

I can get it in the below Lollipop version but not any working source which is working for above Lollipop.

I am using *GET_TASKS* Permission but it deprecated for above KitKat Android Version.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

How can I get currently open Application in android?

```
    public class ApplicationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public final String TAG = "QnA_ApplicationReceiver";
        int co = 0;
        String[] messagnerPack;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context aContext, Intent anIntent) {

        messagnerPack = aContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.smsAppPackage);
        try {
            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) aContext.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> alltasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            Log.i("current task :", "CURRENT Activity ::" + alltasks.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());

            for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo aTask : alltasks) {

                // Used to check for CALL screen
                if (aTask.topActivity.getClassName().equals("com.android.phone.InCallScreen") || aTask.topActivity.getClassName().equals("com.truecaller.ui.TruecallerInit") || aTask.topActivity.getClassName().equals("com.android.contacts.DialtactsActivity") || aTask.topActivity.getClassName().contains("com.android.dialer")) {

                    // When user on call screen show a alert message
                    Toast.makeText(aContext, "Phone Call Screen.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                // Used to check for SMS screen
                if (isSMSApp(aTask.topActivity.getClassName()) || isSMSApp(aTask.baseActivity.getClassName())) {

                    Toast.makeText(aContext, "SMS App is Active.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                // Used to check for CURRENT example main screen
                String packageName = aContext.getPackageName();

                if (aTask.topActivity.getClassName().equals(packageName + ".MainActivity")) {
                    // When opens this example screen then show a alert message

                    //Toast.makeText(aContext, "Running QnA.vbagetech.com Application.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


                Log.i(TAG, "_________________________________");
                Log.i(TAG, "aTask.baseActivity: " + aTask.baseActivity.flattenToShortString());
                Log.i(TAG, "aTask.baseActivity: " + aTask.baseActivity.getClassName());
                Log.i(TAG, "aTask.topActivity: " + aTask.topActivity.flattenToShortString());
                Log.i(TAG, "aTask.topActivity: " + aTask.topActivity.getClassName());
                Log.i(TAG, "_________________________________");
            }

        } catch (Throwable t) {            
            Log.i(TAG, "Throwable caught: " + t.getMessage(), t);
        }
    }

    boolean isSMSApp(String pack) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < messagnerPack.length; i++) {
            if (pack.indexOf(messagnerPack[i]) != -1 ? true : false) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
}
```

App Array from String.XML

```
<string-array name="smsAppPackage">
        <item>com.google.android.apps.messaging</item>
        <item>com.android.mms</item>
        <item>com.whatsapp</item>
        <item>com.jb.gosms</item>
</string-array>
```

By searching, people say that you have to use

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

but it is giving me error *Permission is only granted to system apps* for above versions.

Please help me how can I resolve this for the above versions.

MY MAIN MOTO IS DISABLE SMS APP FOR THE USER.

Comment: you might have to add some more permissions

Comment: Which permission I have to use?

Comment: Google has stated its reasons for deprecating `getRunningTasks` et al: _As of Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP, this method is no longer available to third party applications: the introduction of document-centric recents means it can leak personal information to the caller. For backwards compatibility, it will still return a small subset of its data: at least the caller's own tasks, and possibly some other tasks such as home that are known to not be sensitive"_. So what you're trying to do is not supported for 3rd party (non-system) apps.

Comment: I want to disable SMS App for the user to a condition and the user can access again after my app Service Finish.